# ¿Cómo se definen las colecciones?

Tags: java

Que diferencia hay en crear y definir estas clases,
por ejemplo:

```
HashMap<Object, Object> mapa = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
```

o así:

```
Map<Object, Object> mapa = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
```

o así:

```
Map<Object, Object> mapa = new HashMap<>();
```

También:

```
HashSet<Object, Object> mapa = new HashSet<Object, Object>();
```

o así:

```
Set<Object, Object> mapa = new HashSet<Object, Object>();
```

o así:

```
Set<Object, Object> set = new HashSet<>();
```

También:

```
ArrayList<Object> lista = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

o así:

```
List<Object> lista = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

...así sucesivamente con las colecciones...
¿Cual es la mejor definición de clase? o porque es más preferible o más recomendable dependiendo para que lo quiero utilizar...o ¿Es que hay formas más correctas?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Que diferencia hay en crear y definir estas clases,
>   por ejemplo:
>
> ```
> HashMap<Object, Object> mapa = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
> ```
>
> o así:
>
> ```
> Map<Object, Object> mapa = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
> ```

En la primera construcción estás *declarando* un objeto map de tipo `HashMap` y *definiendo* a map como un objeto que es instancia de la clase `HashMap`. En la segunda construcción estás *declarando* un objeto de tipo `Map` y *definiendo* a map como un objeto que es instancia de la clase `HashMap`. La segunda construcción sigue un patrón conocido como 'programar contra la interfaz': `Map` es una [interfaz](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html), por lo tanto define un conjunto de métodos que las clases que implementen esta interfaz deben completar. La clase `HashMap` implementa la interfaz `Map`, y por lo tanto se compromete a implementar todos los métodos que la interfaz `Map` defina.

En virtud de la herencia en Java, una clase `A` que extiende o implementa una clase o interfaz `B` implica que un objeto de la clase `A` **es un** objeto de la clase `B`. Veamos un ejemplo:

```
public interface Animal {
    public void nutrirse();
    public void reproducirse();
    public void moverse();
}
```

La interfaz `Animal` define tres métodos que cualquier cosa que se pueda decir que es un animal podría hacer: nutrirse, reproducirse o moverse. Cualquier clase que implemente la interfaz `Animal` debe implementar estos métodos, por ejemplo, un perro:

```
public class Dog implements Animal {
    public void nutrirse() {
        //Atragantarse con croquetas para perros
    }
    public void reproducirse() {
        //Encontrar otro perro o perra para poder aparearse
    }
    public void moverse() {
        //Correr rápidamente mientras bate la cola
    }
}
```

o un gato:

```
public class Cat implements Animal {
    public void nutrirse() {
        //Comer moderadamente y con elegancia dejando la mitad de la comida en el plato
    }
    public void reproducirse() {
        //Encontrar otro gato o gata para poder aparearse haciendo intensos ruidos
    }
    public void moverse() {
        //Caminar con elegancia mientras maulla
    }
}
```

Ambas clases implementan la interfaz `Animal` porque *completan* las definiciones de los métodos que la interfaz obliga a tener. Es claro que cada una de estas implementa los métodos de una forma distinta (porque no todos los animales se comportan de la misma manera). Gracias a esto es posible hacer cosas como:

```
Animal snoopy = new Dog(); //un Dog es un Animal
Animal bolaDeNieve = new Cat(); //Un Cat es un Animal
```

Al hacer esto estamos programando contra la interfaz, tanto `snoopy` como `bolaDeNieve` se definen como interfaces pero se declaran como sus clases especializadas. Por otra parte es obvio que también podemos hacer:

```
Dog scooby = new Dog();
Cat garfield = new Cat();
```

pero no podemos hacer

```
Animal engendro = new Animal();
```

porque no podemos declarar objetos de tipo interfaz. ¿Cuál es la ventaja de programar contra interfaz? una muy reconocida es el uso de polimorfismo, supongamos que tenemos una veterinaria que atiende perros y gatos y tenemos varios animales:

```
Dog perro1 = new Dog();
Dog perro2 = new Dog();
Cat gato1 = new Cat();
Cat gato2 = new Cat();
```

Cuando los animales llegan a la veterinaria, se anestesian para poder operarlos, en virtud del polimorfismo podemos crear un método llamado `anestesiarPerro` que reciba un perro y lo anestesie:

```
public void anestesiarPerro(Dog dog) {
    //Procedimiento para anestesiar
    dog.moverse(); //Porque se debe trasladar a la sala de cirugía
    //Más procedimientos para anestesiar
}
```

O anestesiar un gato:

```
public void anestesiarGato(Cat cat) {
    //Procedimiento para anestesiar
    cat.moverse(); //Porque se debe trasladar a la sala de cirugía
    //Más procedimientos para anestesiar
}
```

Dado que el método es genérico, podemos usar polimorfismo para que reciba la interfaz `Animal` e invocar al método `anestesiar` con un objeto de cualquier subtipo de `Animal` tanto presentes (`Cat`, `Dog`) como futuros (mañana la veterinaria puede anestesiar pájaros `Bird`):

```
public void anestesiarAnimal(Animal animal) {
    //Procedimiento para anestesiar
    animal.moverse(); //Ya que se pasa un objeto que es un `Animal` se tiene la seguridad que implementa el método `moverse`
    //Más procedimientos para anestesiar
}
```

Existen muchas más aplicaciones que benefician el programar contra la interfaz, por ejemplo, hacer uso de un patrón de diseño conocido como 
[inversión de control](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inversi%C3%B3n_de_control) y permite aplicar el [principio de sustitución de Liskov](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principio_de_sustituci%C3%B3n_de_Liskov). Volviendo al ejemplo señalado, definir `mapa` como `Map` y no como `HashMap` permite usar este objeto en métodos que reciban la clase más general posible (interfaz) garantizando flexibilidad en el código.

De la misma manera:

> ```
> HashSet<Object, Object> mapa = new HashSet<Object, Object>();
> ```
>
> o así:
>
> ```
> Set<Object, Object> mapa = new HashSet<Object, Object>();
> ```
>
> o así:
>
> ```
> ArrayList<Object> lista = new ArrayList<Object>();
> ```
>
> o así:
>
> ```
> List<Object> lista = new ArrayList<Object>();
> ```

Tanto `List` como `Set` son interfaces y `ArrayList` y `HashSet` implementaciones de estas interfaces. Dado que se prefiere lo más general (las interfaces sobre las implementaciones) se aconseja siempre definir estos objetos con el tipo de la interfaz y declararlos con la implementación subtipo de la interfaz.

---

Por otra parte:

> ```
> Map<Object, Object> mapa = new HashMap<>();
> ```

Es idéntico a

```
Map<Object, Object> mapa = new HashMap<Object, Object>();
```

desde Java 7 el operador diamante (<>) es una característica del lenguaje que le permite al compilador intuir cuál es el tipo de dato que el objeto genérico debe tener al lado derecho de la asignación`a partir de la información del tipo de dato genérico a la izquierda de la asignación. Si te das cuenta, declaras un objeto`Map`cuyas llaves son de tipo`Object`y valores de tipo`Object`, por lo tanto, al usar el operador`<>` sin ningún tipo de dato genérico, el compilador asume que el tipo de dato genérico es el mismo que el señalado en la definición de la variable, un ejemplo:

```
List<Dog> perros = new ArrayList<Dog>();
```

crea un arreglo de `Dog`. Fíjate en la redundancia al declarar el tipo de dato genérico `Dog` en `List<Dog>` y en `ArrayList<Dog`. Usando el operador diamante es equivalente:

```
List<Dog> perros = new ArrayList<>();
```

Ya que a partir de `List<Dog>` es posible intuir que el tipo de dato genérico de `ArrayList<>` es `ArrayList<Dog>`. Señalo nuevamente que esto sólo es posible desde Java 7. En Java 5 y 6 es obligatorio escribir el tipo de dato del genérico tanto a la izquierda como a la derecha de la declaración o asignación de un genérico. Este operador, en últimas sólo funciona como azúcar sintáctico para disminuir la verbosidad del lenguaje.

Comment: Corrección: `En En la primera construcción estás declarando un objeto mapa de tipo HashMap `. Lo que declaras es una referencia/variable. Ejemplo trivial, `Map<String, String> mapa = null` no declara ningún *objeto*.

Answer (score 1):

Antes de empezar: En realidad, tus ejemplos deberían ser

```
Set<Object, Object> set = new HashSet<Object, Object>();
```

o, a partir de Java 7, también vale

```
Set<Object, Object> set = new HashSet<>();
```

De lo contrario, estás asignando una expresión que no tiene definidos los genéricos (un *unbound value*) a una que sí los tiene y te muestra un warning.

Sobre el meollo de la pregunta, no tiene nada que ver con generics en sí. También se podía hacer antes de que se definieran generics (en Java 5), y desde luego, se sigue podiendo hacer con cualquier clase siempre que la variable a la que se asigna sea un supertipo de la expresión asignada. Ejemplo trivial `Object obj = new Integer(1)`.

Lo que aquí haces es definir el tipo de una variable. La regla general es que debes escoger como clase de la referencia la clase más genérica (= más arriba en la jerarquía) con la que puedas trabajar.

Por ejemplo, quieres tener una referencia que se comporte como una lista (puedes añadir elementos y recuperarlos según su posición). Hacer

```
Object miLista = new ArrayList<String>();
```

no tiene mucho sentido, porque la clase `Object` no define un método para añadir objetos a la colección; si haces `miLista.add("Hola");` tienes un error de compilación.

Así, te es más práctico definir la variable/referencia como `List miLista`, ya que así ya puedes invocar al método `add` de la implementeación de `List` que escojas.

¿Y porqué no `ArrayList miLista<String> = new ArrayList<>();`? Pues porque restringes sin necesidad el tipo de valores que puedes asignar. Si todo lo que vas a usar son métodos definidos en el interface `List`, si usas una referencia `ArrayList` restringirás tu código a esa implementación sin necesidad. Un ejemplo muy claro es en los parámetros de los métodos, imagina que tienes un método para duplicar el último elemento de la lista:

```
 public void duplicar(List<Object> lista) {
    if (!lista.isEmpty()) {
       Object obj = lista.get(lista.size() - 1);
       lista.add(obj)
    }
 }

 public void duplicar(ArrayList<Object> lista) {
    if (!lista.isEmpty()) {
       Object obj = lista.get(lista.size() - 1);
       lista.add(obj)
    }
 }
```

La primera versión la puedes usar con cualquier implementación de `List`, mientras que para usar el segundo sólo podrás hacerlo si tienes un `ArrayList` o creas un `ArrayList` a partir de tu lista

Comment: Gracias por la corrección @SJuan76.

Comment: Pues si, es lo que dice nuestro compañero @SJuan76, no se como vayas con los detalles de Java, pero si te lees un poco y vas navegando por la documnenbtación te vas a dar cuenta que, en ocasiones, usas variables de interfaces a las cuales les asignas una implementación de dicha interfaz, el caso mas claro es `List<T>`

Comment: O sea una vez corregida mi pregunta, utilizar mas implementación en un sola linea, concretamente si pones su supertipo, adiere mas funcionalidad en un solo línea.

Comment: Si vas hacia arriba (superclases) tienes más flexibilidad; si vas hacia abajo (subclases) tienes funcionalidad. Se aconseja usar la clase que te ofrezca toda la funcionalidad que necesitas pero lo más flexible posible.